# How Do I Mark Something as Acknowledged?

Tags: help

I am new to Salesforce and I was just asked to mark an activity as acknowledged, after I have just finished printing out and mailing out envelopes regarding a ticket-return donation to my office. However, I cannot find where the box is to mark it properly.

Can anyone tell me where to find this box? I thought I had seen it before, but I cannot find it now, and it is very frustrating.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tasks can be marked as completed from the home page using the X link under the Complete column (be sure to click Save), or you can edit the task and change the status to "Completed" (or whatever value your administrator or trainer told you to use). If there is indeed a box, your administrator would have configured that field. You should contact your system administrator or trainer for specific details. Since Salesforce is a highly customizable system, it's entirely possible that your organization has a unique process to follow for acknowledging tasks.